# Let $T:\mathbb C^3\to\mathbb C^3$.Then, adjoint $T^*$ of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Let $T:\mathbb C^3\to\mathbb C^3$ be defined by $T(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1-iz_2  \\
   iz_1+z_2 \\
z_1+z_2+iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$. Then, the adjoint $T^*$ of $T$.

(A)$T^*(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1+iz_2  \\
   -iz_1+z_2 \\
z_1+z_2-iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

(B)$T^*(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1-iz_2+z_3  \\
   -iz_1+z_2+z_3 \\
iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

(C)$T^*(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1+iz_2+z_3  \\
   iz_1+z_2+z_3 \\
iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

(D)$T^*(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)=  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   iz_1+z_2  \\
   z_1-iz_2 \\
z_1-z_2-iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$

**My attemtpt:-**
I found matrix with respect to the basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. $[T]_{\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}}^{\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}}=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & i&1 \\
   -i & 1 & 1\\
0&0&i\\
  \end{array} } \right]=A(say)
$. Then I found the Hermitian$(A^H)$. Then, I got $T^*(
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]
)= A^H.\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1  \\
   z_2  \\
z_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]= \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   z_1+iz_2  \\
   -iz_1+z_2 \\
z_1+z_2-iz_3\\
  \end{array} } \right]$. (A) is correct according to this steps. Am I correct? Please help me. Is there any simple alternative method to find the adjoint?

Comment: Isn't it just the conjugate transpose?

Comment: Find the matrix, compute the conjugate transpose and express it as above.

Comment: @LeviathanTheEsper Can I generalize to this type of problems like this?